# Make background-color darker dynamically without making text color darker

Tags: css

I want to dynamically make the `background-color` of every button darker on `hover`, I want to add it to my `globals.css` so that it works dynamically regardless of the `background-color` of the button. I have tried using `filter: brightness()` but this affects color of the text too, I want to only make the `background-color` darker. Can this be achieved with `css` only?
I have tried this:

```
button {
  transition: 300ms;
  background:#somecolor;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(80%)
  color: #FFF;
}
```

But this will affect color of the text, which is something I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different methods I came up with this solution using `box-shadow`.

```css
box-shadow: -200px -200px 0px 200px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) inset
/* This is an inset `box-shadow` and will not affect the color of the text. */
```

Cross platform solution:

```css
box-shadow: -200px -200px 0px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: -200px -200px 0px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: -200px -200px 0px 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.10) inset;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [color scheme techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme):

On root declare your initial values then update the colors with `calc()` function in the pseudo-class `:hover`:

```css
:root {
  --H-value: 200;
  --S-value: 30%;
  --L-value: 43%;
  --button-color: hsl(var(--H-value), var(--S-value), var(--L-value));
  --button-hover-color:hsl(var(--H-value), var(--S-value), calc(var(--L-value) + 35%));
}
.button {
  background-color:var(--button-color);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color:var(--button-hover-color);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this, this will set all buttons to be a background color on hover

```
button:hover {
 background-color: black;//set and rgb color here or whatever
}
```

This can also be used with classes like so:

```
button.myButton:hover {
 background-color: black;//set and rgb color here or whatever
}
```

you could also edit opacity but that doesn't change color, it makes it see through so up too you there.

Comment: I already mentioned this will be on the globals.css, meaning I will have multiple buttons, that will probably have different background-color's